# Android app is stuck installing not from Google Play

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, parse-platform, adb

I have an app that uses push notifications via parse.com and posts it to the server.

The app works fine from Eclipse, however when I'm trying to install it from downloads via link in the browser it is stuck.

I'm using this line which is suppose to be in the class that extends application according to the parse tutorials:

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

It is stuck on this line and doesn't get through according to my log. Does anyone might know why?

Comment: You might want to take what you posted and distill it into something a bit more concentrated. Imagine you're writing an e-mail to your coworker. It is very hard for us to read paragraphs and paragraphs and figure out what you want. Give a couple of sentences of background, explain what you need to, then state your question explicitly. That way, it'll be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: got it ! thanks tried to simplify it .
also found out its in parse installation problem hope it makes it more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after dealing with this for a while i found out that doing all the initialization in the application class but saving it right before i post with . 
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().save() **instead of** ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
the difference is that saveInBackground creates a different thread to save the installation and the other saves it without creating a thread meaning thread responsibility is on you.
so i have a thread that handles all the posts out of my app and i used save() in that thread.
that worked for me.